# How do I use df.astype() inside apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a data frame in which all the data in columns are of type object. Now I want to convert all objects into numeric types using astype() function but I don't want to do something like this ->

`df.astype({'col1': 'int32' , 'col2' : 'int32' ....})`

If I do something like this ->

[image]

I get an error because apply function needs Series to traverse.

PS: The other option of doing the same thing is ->

`df.apply(pd.to_numeric)`

But I want to do this using .astype()
Is there any other way instead of using df.apply() and still convert all object type data into numeric using df.astype()

Answer (score 1):

Use  `df = df.astype(int)` to convert all columns to int datatype

```
import numpy

df.astype(numpy.int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

If these are `object` columns and you're certain they can be "soft-casted" to int, you have two options:

```
df
  worker day    tasks
0      A   2     read
1      A   9    write
2      B   1     read
3      B   2    write
4      B   4  execute

df.dtypes

worker    object
day       object
tasks     object
dtype: object
```

#### pandas <= 0.25

[`infer_objects`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) (0.21+ only) casts your data to numpy types if possible.

```
df.infer_objects().dtypes

worker    object
day        int64
tasks     object
dtype: object
```

#### pandas >= 1.0

[`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) casts your data to the most specific pandas extension dtype if possible.

```
df.convert_dtypes().dtypes

worker    string
day        Int64
tasks     string
dtype: object
```

Also see [this answer by me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60278450/4909087) for more information on "hard" versus "soft" conversions.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the safest is to use `pd.to_numeric` in your `apply` function which also allows you error manipulation, `coerce`, `raise` or `ignore`. After getting the columns to numeric, then you can safely perform your `astype()` operation, but I wouldn't suggest it to begin with:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
```

If the column can't be converted to numeric, it will remain unchanged

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

The columns will be converted to numeric, the values that can't be converted to numeric in the column will be replaced with `NaN`.

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='raise')
```

`ValueError` will be returned if the column can't be converted to numeric